# C# 7.3 ref return with pinvoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke, c#-7.3

I would like to know what the difference is in using a ref return versus a pointer when doing pinvokes. The native method signature that I am calling is:

```
typedef struct Buffer {
    const void* Data;
    size_t Length;
} Buffer;

__declspec(dllexport) extern Buffer* GetNewBuffer();
```

On the C# end I have the `Buffer` struct mapped one to one.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Buffer
{
    public IntPtr Data;
    public UIntPtr Length;
}
```

I also have two static methods that call the native function implemented like so:

```
[DllImport("testlib", EntryPoint = "GetNewBuffer")]
public static extern unsafe Buffer* GetNewBufferPointer();

[DllImport("testlib", EntryPoint = "GetNewBuffer")]
public static extern ref Buffer GetNewBufferReference();
```

These two methods compile down to the following MSIL:

```
.method public hidebysig static pinvokeimpl("testlib" as "GetNewBuffer" winapi) 
    valuetype TestInterop.Buffer* GetBufferPointer () cil managed preservesig 
{
} // end of method Native::GetBufferPointer

.method public hidebysig static pinvokeimpl("testlib" as "GetNewBuffer" winapi) 
    valuetype TestInterop.Buffer& GetBufferReference () cil managed preservesig 
{
} // end of method Native::GetBufferReference
```

Using these methods and accessing the returned structs members would look something like this:

```
unsafe
{
    Buffer* bufferPointer = Native.GetBufferPointer();
    var dataFromPointer = bufferPointer->Data;
}

ref Buffer bufferReference = ref Native.GetBufferReference();
var dataFromReference = bufferReference.Data;
```

Is there any difference between these two methods besides the different syntax used to store the return value and access its members? When using ref return with pinvoke, does the GC do anything special that I should be aware of?

Comment: It is fine, no GC problems.  There is still a memory management issue, it ought to gnaw at your conscience a bit whether or not the storage for that struct needs to be released.  Never encouraging when the C function declaration is not `const Buffer*`.  You can't do so reliably, so that helps.  Feel good about that by testing this function by calling it a hundred million times.  If memory usage doesn't explode then you're good.